# Django Query How to compare field with _set filter condition?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have following model

```
class Reply(BaseModel):
    reply_to = models.OneToOneField(
        Review,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        error_messages={'unique': 'Reply to this review already exists.'})
    replied_by = models.ForeignKey(HotelUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Basically  Review model is linked with foreign key with reservation

```
class Review(BaseModel):
    reservation = models.ForeignKey(Reservation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and My Reservation Model has Room   as Foreign Key as

```
class Reservation(BaseModel):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and Room is linked with Hotel in Foreign key

```
class Room(BaseModel):
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and I have certain staff model which have hotel as Foreign key in this way

```
class Staff(BaseModel):
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.OneToOneField(HotelUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My problem is I want the replied by user which is basically ->hotel user lets say   `XYZ` is `Staff` of  `XYZ` hotel.

I tried this in `clean` method:

```
def clean(self):
    if not self.replied_by.reservation.room.hotel.staff_set.filter(user=replied_by) == self.replied_by:
     raiseError
```

but there is no any change on restrication any help will be helpful.

Comment: `filter()` will return you a QuerySet, so your `==` comparison will not work (basically  you are comparing a list of objects to just one object). I think in this case, using `.exists()` would be enough, so: `self.replied_by.reservation.room.hotel.staff_set.filter(user=replied_by).exists()`

Comment: thanks I did same you may write your answer for acceptance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use:

```
self.replied_by.reservation.room.hotel.staff_set.filter(user=self.replied_by).exists()
```